# Why is my window resizing itself? (Cocoa app)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I was creating a simple GUI for an app, and came across this seemingly unusual behaviour when running.

Here is what my xib file looks like:

[image: When designing]

And here is what happens when I run the app:

[image: When running]

I have tried creating a new view and using that instead, but it displays the same behaviour.

Why is the window getting resized? And more importantly, how can you prevent it from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: So is that IB screenshot of a view or a window?  Have you checked the size attributes of the window?  The view will resize to the content size of the window...

Comment: That solved it! My main window was in a separate xib, so I didn't think to look there.

Answer (score 0):

Increase main window width and hight.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem lately with Xcode's auto-layout feature. I solved it by manually deleting all the constraints and using the "Editor->Resolve Auto-Layout Issues->Reset to Suggested Constraints in Window.

Comment: That will affect the subviews, not the view itself.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use Auto Layout Constraints or Springs and Struts (old style ) to configure your views. The window normally will adjust itself as needed with auto layout. 
With old style you have to manage the window frame or at least its content view frame.

Comment: That will affect the subviews, not the view itself.

Comment: Windows are not views.

Answer (score 0):

Go to .xib file

and select size inspector. and from that set autosizing according to your rquirement.

Feel free to contact.